# PMP certification will it help MY career profile

Tags: pmp

I have work experience as a Analyst & Senior Analyst roles totalling 4 years and now in UK into IT recruitment and placements.. where we are going to deal with govt. projects shortly. Would it help me in my career if I do PMP certification. Please help.

Comment: Per our help center, individual career advice is off-topic on Project Management Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

If you are in the UK and are going to be dealing with government projects you are probably better going with [PRINCE2](http://www.prince-officialsite.com/). This has several advantages for you:

- **It is the standard for UK government.** They developed the method and still own it (though there have been some [developments in this regard](http://www.best-management-practice.com/gempdf/Best_Management_Practice_eBulletin_Issue_01.pdf)). It is also apparently heavily used in the private sector in the UK and EU, but I don't have good independent data on hand to support this.
- **It may be of more use to non-project managers.** The method discusses at length the roles of non-project managers in the context of a project. If your role would be as a leader or member of a team delivering one or more of the project's products you would probably get more value from PRINCE2 training than you would from PMP training.
- **It is easier to get.** There are no educational pre-requisites nor documentation of past project experience required.
- **Training is straight-forward.** At least in the UK there are a large number of vendors, both for online and in-person training. In-person training usually takes three days for the initial Foundation exam and an additional two days for the subsequent Practitioner exam

Comment: Any pointers for good training institutes and cost effective ones in London please.

Comment: Mary, if you find Doug's feedback valuable it is common etiquette on the site to up vote his answer and if you find it to be the best answer, to select it as the best answer.

Comment: @Mary, the training should be more variation in quality between individual trainers than between institutes since the training is standardized. I went with Advantage Learning, they are based in Glasgow but run training sessions in London (it appears quarterly). Online training is also provided (I am in North America so had to go that route). You can get schedule, pricing etc at http://www.advantagelearning.co.uk/.

Answer (score 0):

No. While recruiting and Placement can be projects, you don't need to be a PMP to do them and people you will work with won't need/expect it. Since your main focus isn't Project Management, you might just wish to take an introduction to Project Management class, but not go all the way to PMP (or PRINCE2).